# UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification method gets called multiple times

Tags: ios, iphone, accessibility, voiceover

I'm adding my VC as an observer for the UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification notification in viewWillAppear. However, this notification gets called twice when I turn VoiceOver on/off.

Is this normal behaviour? Does VoiceOver have any status other than running or not running?

Answer (score 3):

> ...this notification gets called twice when I turn VoiceOver on/off.

On my side, when I’m listening to the `.voiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification` event, I receive 2 notifications in case of a connection and 3 notifications in case of a disconnection.
[image]

> Is this normal behaviour?

That's **definitely not normal** ⟹ I wrote a **D**eveloper **T**echnical **S**upport **I**ncident *(no 731230503)* for this problem and here's the answer from Apple:

> > We cannot discuss the architecture of the system but I can tell you this a bug [...] Your application should receive only one notification [...] With our currently shipping configurations there is not [a way to get only one notification per event].

I submitted a bug report entitled **The 'VoiceOver Status Did Change Notification' is sent many times for one event** with the reference **FB7628293**.

> Does VoiceOver have any status other than running or not running?

**No, there are just these 2 informations about the VoiceOver status**.
You should receive [only one notification per event](https://a11y-guidelines.orange.com/mobile_EN/dev-ios.html#accessibility-options) and that's clearly not the case unfortunately.

Now, you know why **UIAccessibilityVoiceOverStatusDidChangeNotification method gets called multiple times**... still in iOS 13 and it won't change until this bug is fixed by Apple.